# NAudio - Using WaveIn and AudioEndpointVolume together

Tags: audio, audio-recording, naudio, wasapi

In my app I'm using `WaveIn` to record from mic, and allow my client to adjust the recording level using `AudioEndpointVolume`. I didn't had any problems so far, but since my client may have a different sound card, I would like to ask if this combination may cause any issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be aware that you are using two fundamentally different audio APIs. `WaveIn` is the old "MME" audio subsystem, and `AudioEndpointVolume` is from the new "Core Audio" API introduced with Vista. There is no reason why they shouldn't work together. The main challenge is ensuring that you are definitely controlling the same device with both on systems that have more than one audio input device.

Comment: I guess that `wi = new WaveIn()` will open the default recording device. Than I use `MMDeviceEnumerator.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(DataFlow.Capture, Role.Multimedia)`. Will this ensure that I'm using the same device with both?

Comment: I'd expect so, but can't say for sure I'm afraid. default WaveIn ctr in NAudio will use device 0 which is the default recording device.